# What's the status of std::vector::data()?

Tags: stl, standards-compliance, stdvector

I just realized that I've been using `std::vector::data()` out of similarity with std::string, but a colleague pointed out that it's not standard.

Apparently Gcc implements it, but looking at its include files, I found this comment:

```
  // _GLIBCXX_RESOLVE_LIB_DEFECTS
  // DR 464. Suggestion for new member functions in standard containers.
  // data access
```

My questions are:

- is this method widely implemented by other compilers?
- is it included in C++0x?

(I also wonder what `DR 464` is, and also `_GLIBCXX_RESOLVE_LIB_DEFECTS` for that matter, but I might as well ask another question for those).

Comment: That one hit me yesterday as well, but apparently &(vector.front()) will give you the same result as calling vector.data(), and is standard.

Comment: In c++0x data() == &front() for non-empty vectors according to my copy of the standard document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't comment on current compiler implementations but by looking at the c++0x standard n3290.pdf it is listed at 23.3.6.4.