# Use std::vector in WaitForMultipleObjects()

Tags: c++, vector, waitformultipleobjects

I have an `std::vector` of handle objects. I have to wait on these handle objects for using in the `WaitForMultipleObjects` function. Since it's a vector, I am getting an error while using it in `WaitForMultipleObjects`:

```
std::vector<HANDLE> events;
// ...
WaitForMultipleObjects(events.size(), events, true, INFINITE);
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: As @Joachim said, the second parameter should be a pointer, so why not send `&events[0]` instead of `events`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Preferably, if you've got an up to date version of STL, you should use:

```
WaitForMultipleObjects(events.size(), events.data(), true, INFINITE);
```

With older STL's, you can use &events[0] if .data() isn't available as a method on vector.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the documentation for [`WaitForMultipleObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687025%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you will see that the second argument is a *pointer*, not a `std::vector`. The `std::vector` class can not be used instead of a pointer or native array.

<strike>The only</strike>One way you can do is to create a temporary "array", and copy all the handles to it, and use that as argument.

Another way, as suggested by Charles, is to use `&vector[0]` or as suggested by Tony to use `vector.data()` (if available).

Comment: Only way? What about `&events[0]`.

Comment: @CharlesBailey That will work, but is it portable and "officially sanctioned" (i.e. defined by the standard)?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, yes, standard guarantees that `std::vector`'s elements are consecutive in memory.

Comment: Agree that `&events[0]` is perfectly fine; also you can you `events.data()` - see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data

Comment: But i have to wait on all the handle objects in the vector.

Comment: @TonyDelroy, wow! that's nice, didn't know about the `vector::data` :(

Comment: @AneeshNarayanan, you specify the number of the elements as the first parameter, so it will wait for all of them.

Comment: @unkulunkulu std::vector::data is new with C++11, so if you STL implementation is old, then it might not be available.

Comment: My install of VisualStudio 2010 allows .data() and I've been using it successfully for a while.

Comment: This is weird, the cppreference doesn't mark it as C++11. There's also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6212572/whats-the-status-of-stdvectordata

Answer (score 1):

You should do it like this

```
WaitForMultipleObjects(events.size(), &events[0], true, INFINITE);
```

This is portable and the-way-to-do-it.

Answer (score 1):

The canonical way to get to the underlying vector buffer is

```
&events[0]
```

So you can do this:

```
WaitForMultipleObjects(events.size(), &events[0], true, INFINITE);
```

Also see [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1339470/57428).